# Django-filter. Lookup expression doesn't work properly

Tags: django, django-filter

When I use `MultipleChoiceFilter` with `lookup_expr='iexact'` it looks like the parameters are still case sensitive and `Select a valid choice` is returned. What am I doing wrong?

**It's my filter class:**

```
class PostFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    lang = filters.MultipleChoiceFilter(
        field_name='language', choices=[('ENG', 'ENG'), ('DEU', 'DEU')], lookup_expr='iexact')

    class Meta:
        fields = ('lang',)
        model = Post
```

**Request:** `posts/?lang=eng&lang=deu`

**Response:** `Select a valid choice. eng is not one of the available choices.`

**My DB:** `PostgreSQL 14`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your request should be `posts/?lang=ENG&lang=DEU` as the values will first be validated against the definition in the filter class. `lookup_expr='iexact'` will be used later for the database lookup. If you want to use the lower case values you would have to change your choices to `choices=[('eng', 'ENG'), ('deu', 'DEU')]`.